# Solved CS50 Readability but I don't know why I need to initial the num to 1 in count_words (line 63)

Tags: c, cs50

I solved this problem by initializing num to 1 as it is the only way I know to get the actual word count. But I don't see the logic behind it and it's not good practice to fix it without understanding what is happening. Also, how do I post code, it keeps telling me "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." But I have nothing else to write.........

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int main(void)
{
    string input; // get input, making sure it does not start with space
    do
    {
        input = get_string("Text: ");
    }
    while (input[0] == ' ');

    // CALCULATION
    int letters = count_letters(input);
    int words = count_words(input);
    int sentences = count_sentences(input);

    float L =
        ((float) letters / words) * 100; // need float or it will truncate removing the remainder as it is two int getting divided
    float S = ((float) sentences / words) * 100;

    int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    if (index > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }

    else if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", index);
    }
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < l; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int num = 1; // number should start from 1 for our purpose????? maybe the

    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < l; i++)
    {
        if (isspace(text[i]))
        {
            num++;
            if (isspace(text[i + 1])) // eliminating double spaces in between sentences
            {
                num--;
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < l; i++)
    {

        if (text[i] == '?')
        {
            num++;
        }
        if (text[i] == '!')
        {
            num++;
        }
        if (text[i] == '.')
        {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Can you count your 5 fingers by counting the 'gaps' between them? The extra 1 is for the last word that, presumably, is not followed by a SP...

Comment: Side note: In `count_words`, you could eliminate the second `if` by changing the first to `isspace(text[i]) && !isspace(text[i+1])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment some hours ago, I pointed out the reason for the perplexing `int num = 1;` when counting words. This is fine as far as it goes, but it is still a bit of a problem.

What is the number of words in the string `""` or a string like `"....."` that appears to contain 5 sentences?

Not only is `1 word` wrong, but any overly simple correction to `0` would lead to *division by zero*.

I do not have, and cannot test, the CS50 function `get_string()`, but your code suggests you reject strings with leading spaces, and, perhaps, the function trims trailing spaces. Hard to say.

Here's a modified version of one function that increments the counter at the **start** of any word (including the case of a single word in the string.)

```
int count_words(string text)
{
    int num = 0;
    int inWord = 0; // a 'flag' set to 1 at the start and interior of any word

    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < l; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i])
        {
            if( inWord == 0 ) // have not been in a word
                num++; // count this word
            inWord = 1; // in a word now. No consequence of setting of flag repeatedly
        }
        else
            inWord = 0; // not alpha? out of any word
    }
    return num;
}
```

This also skirts the problem of *multiple consecutive spaces*. It counts when a word begins; not the gaps between words.

I'll leave it to you to add code to test that there is at least one "word" before doing the calculations in `main()`.

You might also consider whether "R2D2" or "C3PO" should be counted as a single word... George Lucas wants to know...

---

Bonus info:
By definition, a C string will be terminated with a NUL character (`'\0'`). You can take advantage of this and save yourself measuring the string prior to looping through each and every character:

```
    for (int i = 0; text[ i ] != '\0'; i++) // terminate loop at end of string
```

This can be made even simpler knowing that the *zero value* of that last byte equates to `false`.

```
    for (int i = 0; text[ i ]; i++) // terminate loop at end of string
```

C is a wonderful language, don't you think?

Comment: The code does reject strings starting with space and does trim trailing spaces, but your code is more concise and the design is much better. Thanks for the bonus too, there are many loops in CS50 so It will definitely help. Tho I don't know what to do for George Lucas...maybe I'll include numbers haha

Comment: @AshleyJadenSamson Thanks. Because this version counts 'words' as the transition from something else to the first alphabetic character, leading and/or trailing spaces will not affect the count. Perhaps this will broaden the range of text samples the program can handle. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To try to be as succinct as possible, the need for initializing your "num" integer variable to an initial value of "1" accounts for the fact that the space testing for the last word in your text string will not trigger any increment of that variable as the for loop will end at the end of the text string length.  Following, is a code snippet for your "count_words" with a bit of code and comment tweaking.

```
int count_words(string text)
{
    int num = 1;                // Account for the fact that incrementing this variable will not occur when the last word is being processed.
    int l = strlen(text);       // Clarifies what will be happening in the following for loop.

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) // Clarified/simpler for loop.
    {
        if (isspace(text[i]))
        {
            num++;
            if (isspace(text[i + 1])) // Eliminating double spaces in between sentences
            {
                num--;
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

I kept your code intact except for moving the initialization of the "l" integer variable up at the beginning of the function block, just to make things clearer for anyone subsequently analyzing the code.  And I added in revised comments to hopefully clarify the need for the variable initialization.

Go ahead and review these tweaks and see if it assists you in furthering your code studies.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Just starting out now, so I guess I'll get better with succinctness with time. And using clearer comments too.